# SQL query for most recent date

Tags: sql

I'm trying to query to only pull the most recent sale date but keep the unique value of "strap". This is the query result I have.

```
nh_cd   strap      dor_cd   acreage sqft    sale date               reception_num   price   asd_val rea_cd  
178.00  R0000001   AG       4.7160  205443  2019-07-11 00:00:00.000 3723615         890000  200     05   
178.00  R0000001   AG       4.7160  205443  2020-05-29 00:00:00.000 3787823         880000  200     40  
205.00  R0022222   AGRES    5.8030  252771  2019-06-10 00:00:00.000 3718473         647500  520200  40
```

This is what I've built so far, but it doesn't give me my desired result of a recent date.

```
SELECT distinct
parcel.nh_cd
,sales.strap
,parcel.dor_cd
,detail.acreage
,detail.sqft
,max(sales.dos)
,sales.reception_num
,sales.price
,parcel.asd_val
,sales.rea_cd
,sales.qu_flg
,sales.valid_cd
,sales.vi
,site.str_num
,site.str_pfx
,site.str
,site.str_sfx
,site.city
,parcel.status_cd
,strap_idx.folio

FROM detail INNER JOIN parcel ON parcel.strap = detail.strap 
INNER JOIN sales ON parcel.strap = sales.strap 
INNER JOIN site ON parcel.strap = site.strap 
INNER JOIN strap_idx ON parcel.strap = strap_idx.strap 
INNER JOIN lnd_a ON parcel.strap = lnd_a.strap 

WHERE lnd_a.st_use_cd IN ('4117','4127','4137','4147','4167','4177','4180')
AND parcel.dor_cd LIKE 'AG%'
AND parcel.status_cd = 'A'
AND (sales.price > '0')
AND (site.ln_num = '1')
AND (sales.dos>='07/01/2018')
AND (sales.dos<='08/24/2020')

GROUP by parcel.nh_cd
,sales.strap
,parcel.dor_cd
,detail.acreage
,detail.sqft
,sales.dos
,sales.reception_num
,sales.price
,parcel.asd_val
,sales.rea_cd
,sales.qu_flg
,sales.valid_cd
,sales.vi
,site.str_num
,site.str_pfx
,site.str
,site.str_sfx
,site.city
,parcel.status_cd
,strap_idx.folio
```

This is the result I want

```
nh_cd   strap      dor_cd   acreage sqft    sale date               reception_num   price   asd_val rea_cd  
178.00  R0000001   AG       4.7160  205443  2020-05-29 00:00:00.000 3787823         880000  200     40  
205.00  R0022222   AGRES    5.8030  252771  2019-06-10 00:00:00.000 3718473         647500  520200  40
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `ROW_NUMBER()` it

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT distinct parcel.nh_cd
        ,sales.strap
        ,parcel.dor_cd
        ,detail.acreage
        ,detail.sqft
        ,sales.dos
        ,sales.reception_num
        ,sales.price
        ,parcel.asd_val
        ,sales.rea_cd
        ,sales.qu_flg
        ,sales.valid_cd
        ,sales.vi
        ,site.str_num
        ,site.str_pfx
        ,site.str
        ,site.str_sfx
        ,site.city
        ,parcel.status_cd
        ,strap_idx.folio
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY parcel.nh_cd, sales.strap ORDER BY sales.dos DESC) AS rn
    FROM detail INNER JOIN parcel ON parcel.strap = detail.strap 
    INNER JOIN sales ON parcel.strap = sales.strap 
    INNER JOIN site ON parcel.strap = site.strap 
    INNER JOIN strap_idx ON parcel.strap = strap_idx.strap 
    INNER JOIN lnd_a ON parcel.strap = lnd_a.strap 
    WHERE lnd_a.st_use_cd IN ('4117','4127','4137','4147','4167','4177','4180')
        AND parcel.dor_cd LIKE 'AG%'
        AND parcel.status_cd = 'A'
        AND (sales.price > '0')
        AND (site.ln_num = '1')
        AND (sales.dos>='07/01/2018')
        AND (sales.dos<='08/24/2020')
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Perfect! Quick question, what does "t" do (second to last line)?

Comment: @Taylor It's a table alias.  The inner query returns a table.  You have to name the table.  In this case `t`is the name of the inner query table.